# How serve different content using apache and (maybe) mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, redirect, url

There are some files (with unique names) in a directory structure like this:

```
/var/www/domain1/unique_filename1
/var/www/domain2/unique_filename2
/var/www/domain3/unique_filename3
```

At the moment, all of the domain directories are accessible as sub-directories of a master domain and clients can access the files using following URIs:

```
www.my-master-domain.com/domain1/unique_filename1
www.my-master-domain.com/domain2/unique_filename2
www.my-master-domain.com/domain3/unique_filename3
```

I'd like to modify Apache 2.4 configuration so that I will be able to access files without mentioning secondary domains in my URLs, for example:

```
www.my-master-domain.com/unique_filename1
www.my-master-domain.com/unique_filename2
www.my-master-domain.com/unique_filename3
```

And of course it's not desirable to do any redirect on client browsers (and event If I wanted, it would not be possible in this special case), I just need to directly server the files via second set of mentioned URLs.

Any ideas?

Comment: What would you wish to happen when the filenames in two different directories are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `RewriteMap` that maps "unique" filenames to the *domain* it is stored under. You can then use a `RewriteRule` directive to lookup the *domain* from the requested "unique" filename and *internally rewrite* the request.

For example, in your server config, define the `RewriteMap`:

```
RewriteMap fn2domain "txt:/var/www/filename-to-domain-map.txt"
```

Then, in `/var/www/filename-to-domain-map.txt` you would include all your filename mappings:

```
# Filename to Domain map
unique_filename1 domain1
unique_filename2 domain2
unique_filename3 domain3
```

Now you can use mod_rewrite to reference this map in order to *internally rewrite* a request from `/unique_filename2` to `/domain2/unique_filename2` (for example).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /${fn2domain:$1}/$1 [L]
```

This assumes that "unique_filename" is exactly that; just a filename. No additional URL-path.

You could make the lookup more efficient by using a `dbm:` DBM Hash File (or `fastdbd:` SQL Query?) instead of a plain text file, if you have many "filenames".

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html

---

Alternatively, you could perform filesystem checks for the existence of "unique_filename" in each *domain* subdirectory. The first match wins. This *might* be OK if you only have 2 or 3 domain subdirectories, but if you have many then this might become a performance problem as filesystem checks are relatively expensive. For example, again using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Is it in domain1? Then rewrite to domain1 subdirectory
RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domain1/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /domain1/$1 [L]

# Is it in domain2? Then rewrite to domain2 subdirectory
RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domain2/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /domain2/$1 [L]

# Is it in domain3? Then rewrite to domain3 subdirectory
RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domain3/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /domain3/$1 [L]

# Repeat for each domain...
```